# How can I check if my flour is self-raising or plain?

Tags: flour

If I have some unlabelled flour in the cupboard, is there a way I can determine if it is self-raising flour or plain flour, before cooking with it and just checking if the cake rises? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put your flour in water.  It should be slightly fizzy due to the presence of baking powder if it is active self raising flour.  If it is plain it should react like normal flour.

Comment: I was going to say "Rub some on your gums" but I like your method better.

Comment: and what, detect for a numbing effect in the white powder? haha

Answer (score 6):

Mix equal parts of the flour & white distiled vinegar (dont need much, maybe a tablespoon each).  If its self rising flour, it'll bubble/foam slightly, whereas plain flour will not.

Comment: This sounds like a more reliable method than water, depending on what baking powder formula is used.

Answer (score 1):

Self-rising flour is usually salted. Regular flour isn't. You can taste a tiny bit.

Comment: The self raising flour in my cupboard doesn't have any added salt. It does taste a little bit different to the plain flour though.

Comment: Self **rising** flour is US & does contain salt. Self **raising** flour is UK & does not.